# handling ImageList with windows hooks

Tags: windows, hook, imagelist

I am programming an application that can catching the information about the screen items by Hooks
Now I am trying to get the information of the ImageList when I pass them by mouse, "I want to know the name of the item"

how can i do this?

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of hook are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Images in ImageLists don't have names, so I'm not sure you are talking about the Win32 ImageList. But if you are actually talking about them, you would have to detect the type of control you are over (toolbar,listview etc) and send the control specific message to get the imagelist handle.

If you are NOT talking about ImageLists, but actual controls, I would suggest looking at the [Accessibility API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373592(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I am talking precisely about the icons for example on the desktop and in any folder such as documents and other but at first i say ImageList because when I searched for the Structure of icons I found that they follow the ImageLists and then I ask about it
But the question more precisely, how do I get the names of the icons

Comment: The icons don't have names (I don't think you can get the path to the icon file if that is what you are asking) but you can the the index of a icon in the system image list by calling SHGetFileInfo